# Storing different functions under one function pointer

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers, stack

Please allow me to provide some background to my problem:

I have a university assignment that provides me with a class named **StringList**. This class is responsible for a lot of string operations such as **inserting**, **removing**, etc. Some examples of the function signatures for these method can be seen below:

```
// Must be undoable
void insert_before(int index, const std::string &s)
{
    //...
}

// Must be undoable
void remove_bofore(int index)
{
    //...
}

void undo()
{
    // Attempts to revert back to the last operation
}
```

The assignment requires me to implement a **stack** with the capability to provide an **undo()** operation that essentially **reverses the functionality that took place** previously. For example, if some code decides to call the classes method called **insert_before()**, then the **StringList** class must use the stack to provide the ability to revert back by removing the inserted string operation.

Implementing the stack seems like a rather trivial task to accomplish, but the main problem is trying to figure out how to implement the undo() operation in the easiest way possible. My original thought is to create a **Node** struct that aside from the standard next pointer, which allow it to refer to other nodes, will contain a **function pointer** variable like this:

```
// Used in singly linked list stack
struct Node
{
  Node* next;
  
  void(*function)();
};
```

This helps in storing the desired function that needs to be called in order to undo() the operation that was performed previously. This is done by saving the exact opposite operation that was done last time. For example, if the **insert_before()** method is called, then it will behave like this:

```
void insert_before(int index, const std::string &s)
{
    // Perform the insertion...
    
    stack.push(
        remove_before(index)    // Storing the function that needs to be called by undo()...
    );
}
```

The main issue that I am facing with this approach is that I don't know for sure if we are allowed **to store different function signatures under one common function pointer**. The function pointer clearly expects a function with a signature of **void** for the return type and a parameter of **void** type. But, each of the functions that need to be stored in it have different signatures, and these are only 2 methods there are way more.

I could go ahead and create a function pointer for each method type, but I don't think it is a good idea to create so many different function pointers for each of them.

So, how do I go about this? I mean... is it possible to store all of them under one function pointer? or is there something else I can do with this?

Comment: You might want to consider using lambdas for this, since they can capture extra bindings that might be important (for example, the index at which to perform the operation). The lambda can do whatever you want, but provide a consistent signature (_e.g._ `std::function<void (UndoContext&)>`)

Comment: You don't need to implement your own stack, you can use std::stack. Combine this with comment from @paddy and you can do a `std::stack<std::function<void()>>`  and then you can do : `stack.push([=]{ remove_before(index); })`

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the `std::stack` because I am required to implement a custom one by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need different signatures. The signature will always be `void(StringList &)`, or something similar. `undo()` takes no arguments, so any additional arguments needed to undo need to be baked into the function you're storing.

Use capturing lambdas:

```
stack.push([index](StringList &list)
{
    list.remove_before(index);
});
```

As function pointers can't point to capturing lambdas, use `std::function` instead.

Comment: I am not allowed to use `std::function`. I am sorry ;)

Comment: There are other methods as well though. Some of them have different return types and different amount of parameters and types. Will this solution still work for them as well?

Comment: @Default Please list all restrictions in the question. I don't want to rewrite this using a different feature only to be told that it's not allowed too.

Comment: How is my Node class supposed to be changed in order to take in lambdas that have different signatures and variant amount of parameters and types?

Comment: @Default You don't need to change your class. The lambdas never need additional parameters (nor to return anything), no matter what operation you're undoing. Notice how I'm not passing `index` as a parameter, but rather capturing it.

Comment: Here are all restrictions:

Cannot use `std::function`, `std::bind`, and any other type of standard function provided by C++. I can only use default function pointers or lambdas.

Comment: @Default You should edit that into the question. You can imitate `std::function` with polymorphism: `struct BasicUndoAction {virtual void undo(StringList &) = 0;}; struct UndoInsertion : BasicUndoAction {int index = 0; void undo(StringList &s) override {s.remove_before(index);}};`, and so on.

Comment: Let me try and express what I am having issues understanding:

It is not the lambda itself that is confusing me in terms of parameters or types. You are indeed correct that these can be altered. The problem is that this lambda needs to be stored somewhere in a function pointer and I don't understand how a function that is declared to be void return type and 1 parameter can store so many variations in it. I hope this clears what I am having issues with.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment:

In your example, if I understood it correctly, you are taking in a reference to the class "StringList" and capturing [index], so you may declare a function with a lambda that calls the remove method from that class which is absolutely brilliant! But, the issue is how can my Node which can only contain a function pointer of (void)(*function)() contain a function with a different signature? Hope this clears it.

Comment: @Default That signature can't work. Are you forced to use that one? It needs to be `void (*function)(StringList &)` (but since function pointers can't point to capturing lambdas, this needs to be a signature of `std::function` instead, or of a virtual function).

Comment: The only things I can use are function pointers and lambdas. I am not allowed to use `std::function`, so I guess I am done for ;)

Comment: Is it possible to set the function variable as `auto` and let the compiler deduce the correct type for it for each lambda that gets passed in?

Comment: @Default No, each `auto` is deduced only once at compile-time. "I am done for" No, as I said this can be solved with virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

> store different function signatures under one common function pointer

will make the solution complicated.
Have you heard of command design pattern?
When there is insert_before or remove function is called, you generate a command and cache the command in actions vector.
So when Undo is called, simply pop_back vector and execute it.
Below is the sample code:

```
struct StringList
{
    std::vector<Action> actions;
    
    void insert_before(int index, const std::string &s)
    {
        //...
        
        collections.insert(collections.begin() + index, s);
        
        Action a{.ac = ActionType::remove};
        if (index == 0)
        {
            a.index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            a.index = index - 1;
        }
        actions.push_back(a);
    }
    
    // Must be undoable
    void remove_bofore(int index)
    {
        //...
        Action a{.ac = ActionType::insert,  .s = collections[index], .index = index};
        collections.erase(collections.begin() + index);
        actions.push_back(a);
    }
    
    void undo()
    {
        // Attempts to revert back to the last operation
        if (actions.empty())
        {
            return;
        }
        
        auto action = actions.back();
        actions.pop_back();
        
        if (action.ac == ActionType::remove)
        {
            collections.erase(collections.begin() + action.index);
        }
        else if (action.ac == ActionType::insert)
        {
            collections.insert(collections.begin() + action.index, action.s);
        }
    }
    
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << "size:" << collections.size() << " action size:" << actions.size() << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::vector<std::string> collections;
};

int main()
{
    StringList sl;
    
    sl.insert_before(0, "a");
    sl.print();
    sl.undo();
    
    sl.insert_before(0, "b");
    sl.print();
    sl.undo();
    
    sl.insert_before(0, "c");
    sl.print();
    sl.undo();
    
    sl.insert_before(0, "d");
    sl.insert_before(0, "e");
    sl.print();
    sl.undo();
    sl.undo();
    sl.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wonder how this would look like if you wanted to undo a `clear()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it's easy to implment `clear()`, isn't it? you add a list of insert _before actions and do it in a loop.

Comment: Mhm, but then you need to somehow group them, and it's still less efficient than moving the entire vector around. It helps to have some kind of polymorphism here, be it `std::function` or `std::variant` (this one is most similar to what you do) or something else.